# How to specify what menu is used for the system main menu in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to figure out how to specify which custom menu get's used for the system menu. I know I can include the custom menu in the tpl, but look to override the system_main_menu and tell it to use a different one. I'm assuming I'd do this in a preprocess function, but new to Drupal and not sure where to start. After googling, I've found:

```
links__system_main_menu
```

Guessing that's what I'd use for the preprocess function, but need to know how to then tell it which custom menu to use.

EDIT:

Or maybe the better question would be is how to define the system main menu for a theme using one of the custom menus.

Answer (score 0):

go in your admin

admin/structure/menu/settings

there you can set defaut main menu

UPDATE :
here's what I found on [drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/1246484)

```
function yourtheme_menu_link__main_menu(array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';

  if ($element['#below']) {
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  }

  $element['#localized_options']['html'] = TRUE;
  $linktext = '<span class="your_class">' . $element['#title'] . '</span>';

  $output = l($linktext, $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

PR

Comment: Right, but like I said, I want to be able to overwrite the system menu preferably using a preprocess function. Doing it the way you described, changes the main menu for all themes which I don't want to do.

Comment: why you don't simply use modules like [nice_menus](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus) or [menu_block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) to create a block in your theme using an "instance" of the menu you want.

Comment: Thanks, ended up using the nice_menus module. I'd prefer to simply overwrite the link array with the custom links, less code.

Comment: I would, but it didn't answer my question. I want to figure out how to overwrite the link array with a preprocess function without having to use a module. What you provided is a workaround, not the answer to the question.

Comment: updated my answer, this is with Omega theme but should be similar with your theme